# Grouping sys.dm_exec_connections by database (it's not quite like sys.sysprocesses)

Tags: sql-server, connection

Following on from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744182/test-before-attempting-exclusive-lock):

I've written some code to upgrade a SQL Server database. Before I upgrade the database, I plan to limit access to the database with the following statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE Test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Before running this code, I'll give the user an opportunity to opt out. At the time of prompting the user, I thought it would be nice to show the list of active connections (continuously polled at a set interval); providing the user with a tool to identify applications/users they would like to boot off the server before proceeding.

In SQL 2000, you can use the `sys.sysprocesses` table to see all connections that apply to a database. This includes connections that have no active request (like when you open a Query Analyser window and select a database).

However, using:

- `sys.dm_exec_connections`
- `sys.dm_exec_sessions`; and
- `sys.dm_exec_requests`

I couldn't figure out a way to achieve the same outcome. It appears that these views only tie connections to a database through a request. Is there a way to mimic the behaviour of `sys.sysprocesses`? I'd prefer not to use this table for SQL Server 2005/2008 databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er... I recommended these for your other question.

Sorry, but, I've found out that you still have to use sysprocesses

It's logged as a bug in [Microsoft Connect 144515](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=144515) to be fixed, [I found it here](http://www.windows-tech.info/15/dd2d15df8b55fcdc.php)

Personally, I still use sysprocesses because I'm comfortable with it, however lazy and luddite that may be...

Comment: I deleted a comment on a different thread because someone pointed out that sys.sysprocesses was to become obsolete. And then I found out that up to SQL 2008 you still have to use sys.sysprocesses. In SQL Server 2012 you can find the database_id column in the sys.dm_exec_sessions table. `select database_id, db_name(database_id), des.* from sys.dm_exec_sessions as des`