# how to know how many users are connected to a particular database in sqlserver2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

how to know how many users are connected to a particular database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stored procedure `sp_who2`

Answer (score 0):

For a simply query, you can use this on SQL 2000 to SQL 2008 ([there is no 1:1 replacement for 
sysprocesses in SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765206/grouping-sys-dmexecconnections-by-database-its-not-quite-like-sys-sysprocesse))

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    MASTER..sysprocesses
WHERE
    dbid = DB_ID('MyDBName')
```

Comment: I believe this query will get you a wrong count if parallel queries are being executed. You're also not removing the system processes from the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT spid)
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE spid >= 50
AND dbid = DB_ID('MyDBName')
```